# puppetrun when the client certname != FQDN

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet client 'my-client' where the certificate name is 'my-clients-certname' instead of the being the same as the hostname.  The puppet client and puppetmaster server have been working fine like this for a while.  However, now I'd like to start using puppetrun on the client as well, and it's giving an unexpected error.

From the server, here's what I'm seeing if I try to run puppetrun:

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]$ puppetrun --debug --host my-client
Triggering my-client
Host my-client failed: Server hostname 'my-client' did not match server certificate; expected my-clients-certname
my-client finished with exit code 2
Failed: my-client
```

I figured if I added the --certname=my-clients-certname argument, that should work, but I get the same 'did not match server certificate output.

```
[root@puppetmaster ~]$ puppetrun --debug --certname=my-clients-certname my-client
Triggering my-client
Host my-client failed: Server hostname 'my-client' did not match server certificate; expected my-clients-certname
my-client finished with exit code 2
Failed: my-client
```

Is there some other way I should be telling puppetrun about the client's certname ?

Comment: I haven't used puppetrun, but isn't the `--host` option used to specify the puppet server?  Shouldn't it just be `puppetrun --debug myclient`?

Comment: 'puppetrun --debug myclient' and 'pupeptrun --debug --host myclient' both give the same 'did not match server certificate' error message.

Comment: @pwan But, what's the hostname returned by the error message?

Comment: What version of puppet are you using and what OS?

Comment: The master is CentOS 6.2 running 2.7.11.  The client is Fedorta 16 running 2.7.17 .  I'll see if I run into the same behaviour with the same OS and puppt versions.